# Android SQLite Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The full error I'm getting is this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Cowboy Bebop(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM anime WHERE title = Cowboy Bebop
```

Also I get this:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Cowboy Bebop(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM anime WHERE title = Cowboy Bebop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use string concatenation to assemble a SQL query this way. You are not properly quoting your value, let alone handle any quotes in the value itself.

Replace queries like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES + " WHERE " + KEY_TITLE + " = " + title;
Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), query);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null); //GETTING ERROR HERE
```

with:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES + " WHERE " + KEY_TITLE + " = ?";
Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), query);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { title });
```

The `?` tells SQLite to bind the supplied argument, handling quoting, escaping of embedded quotes, and so on.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! I'm also running into 1 more problem if you don't mind helping.

Comment: @user2923535: "I'm also running into 1 more problem" -- I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide your (revised) code and an explanation of your problem.

Comment: Okay will do! Thanks again!